# Systemd: keep forked process alive when service is stopped

Tags: linux, systemd

I have a systemd service which forks some child processes.

In one scenario I start a shell script which is supposed to stop the service which actually started the script. When I call `systemd stop xxx.service`, systemd will kill all processes in the service's cgroup, which also includes the shell script.

Is there any way to stop systemd from doing so? I need the script to survive systemd's stopping attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think that [`KillMode=process`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html#KillMode=) in the service definition will do what you want, but it really sounds like you're going about things the wrong way... Maybe this script should be a separate service that the first one requires?

Comment: There is another way to do this? I have the same problem, but I need to keep the `KillMode=control-group`... Can I "schedule" my child process to start with another feature of the SO? I need this to because this child process is an Updater Tool that will download a new version and during this update process I need to stop and after a while I will start it again.

Comment: @BetoNeto I am having the same issue, can you share how you resolved this problem?